# code of model selection in rapidminer mo

Tags: rapidminer

I was watching [this video about automatic model selection in rapidminer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jfYSzMWBWo), but the video resolution is quite low and there's no code provided. Could somebody tell me where I can find some code of similar functionality please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples shipped with RapidMiner Studio. Whilst these are not quite the same as the video, they are relatively close.

In particular, `//Samples/processes/06_Meta/05_OperatorEnabler`, but also others in the `06_Meta` folder.